# Where is valid RSS changes of OpenJDK projects?

Tags: java, java-8

I wanted to be notified about last changes of JDK's project through RSS, for example lambda project. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rss-log seems is not a valid RSS output, so where is valid RSS of OpenJDK projects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2012: Seems there is some bug on OpenJDK Mercurial rss feed output.

2021 update: Apparently is fixed now, http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rss-log although I used to check it with Google Reader which is gone since 2013!

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess.  Are you using the Chrome browser?  It is picky about RSS conformance ...

I suggest you switch Firefox for now to read this RSS feed.  Firefox displays it just fine for me.  And if it really bugs you, see if you can figure out what the problem with this feed is and report it to the site maintainers.

To answer your question: I don't know if there is another RSS feed, but I rather doubt not.

Comment: Hi, yes I am using Chrome :) But according to source of that: view-source:http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rss-log is not a valid RSS. (`<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="/lambda/lambda/jdk/rss-log" title="RSS feed for lambda/lambda/jdk">` is a self link)

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi - Try Firefox then.  It ignores the minor problems in the feed and displays it anyway.

Comment: Sorry, subscribing to this feed was not successful here (also in Google Reader)